# Divs to go vertical on mobile sites

Tags: html

So, I have 3 divs that go horizontal on my webpage. However, when someone accesses the site on a mobile device I don't want the user to have to scroll left/right to view the divs. Here is the very simple code I am using at the minute. I am also using the Opera Mobile Emulator to view the site on mobile.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUPOI.jpg this is what currently happens on mobile devices.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
  @-o-viewport{
    width:device-width;
    zoom:1;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div style = "width:100%">
    <div style = "width:30%; display:inline-block;">
        <div>
            <img src="Mario.png">
        </div>
        <div>
            Test
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style = "width:30%; display:inline-block;">
        <div>
            <img src="Mario.png">
        </div>
        <div>
            Test
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style = "width:30%; display:inline-block;">
        <div>
            <img src="Mario.png">
        </div>
        <div>
            Test
        </div>
    </div>                          
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Start by not putting styles inline. Use classes and CSS. Then, take a look into media queries.

Comment: sorry, this is only a very rough copy of what i needed done, so just did inline styles till i got it running!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Media Queries:

http://jsfiddle.net/p5vdq/1/

```
<div class="con">
    <div class="col">
        <div>
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" />
        </div>
        <div>
            Test
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div>
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" />
        </div>
        <div>
            Test
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div>
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" />
        </div>
        <div>
            Test
        </div>
    </div>                          
</div>

@-o-viewport{ width:device-width; zoom:1; }
.col { width:30%; display:inline-block; }
.con { width:10)%; }

/* 767 */
@media (max-width:767px)                    {
.col { width:100%; display:block; }
}
```

You also had an error in your HTML, be sure to close off img tags ().

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
@media (max-width: 799px) {
    .inner {width: 100%;}
}

.outer {width: 100%;} /* not necessary--divs are block-level by default */
.inner {display: inline-block; width: 30%;}
</style>

<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <div>
            <img src="Mario.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    body > div > div { display: block; width: 100%; }
}
```

I am using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) and giving the inner elements `display: block;` so they stack on top of each other.